# TeamCity error - "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, teamcity

I have TeamCity running on AWS EC2 instances (Unix server + Linux agent). After I restarted server and agent instances I've started receiving an error when running a build:

```
An error occurred while executing 'docker login -u "******" --password-stdin *****************.amazonaws.com':
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I have TeamCity connection for AWS user - after restart the user lost privileges to Docker Server on the agent. I've runner "***sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock***" and now, the user can access Docker Client and Docker Server as well (I see both when running "docker version"). But the error still occurs.

Does anyone have an idea what I've missed?

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock` <= **This is evil** and will not survive a machine reboot / service restart anyway. Add the given user to the docker group => `sudo usermod -aG docker theuser`